# Running a stepper motor at less than rated amps, what's the torque?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a large round stepper I salvaged that is rated for 5A. If I drive it with a 2.5A driver, how will that affect the torque? Will it cut it in half? Is the effect even predictable at all?

Comment: I believe the related post linked below should answer your question in detail, as well as provide direction for further research related questions. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10368/underpowering-a-stepper-motor?rq=1

Comment: Stepper motor torque varies with step "size"(full, half, etc), speed and current and voltage applied. So its a bit hard to accurately predict how much torque you will lose without testing or looking at a datasheet..

Comment: I know its salvaged, but.. does it have a part number?

Comment: I already asked the customer support of the company that made it, after not finding it online. Turns out it was a custom build, so no datasheet. What I know: Anaheim Automation, 4.9A, 0.4Ohm, bipolar, NEMA 34, 2.5 in long.